# pyinfra: how to know when an operation causes a change

Tags: pyinfra

Sometimes, you need to run more commands if one command causes a change on the remote system. Good examples would be:

- You update a systemd service file. If the file was actually changed, then you need to restart the service.
- You update the configuration for a service (like say **/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**). If that file was changed, you need to restart the service.

Is there a way to do this with **files.put**? Ideally you could write code like:

```
changed = files.put(src='files/dhcpd.conf', dest='/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf')
if changed:
    systemd.service(service='isc-dhcp-server', running=True, restarted=True)
```

Comment: See docs on interdependent operations https://docs.pyinfra.com/en/latest/deploy_process.html#interdependent-operations

Answer (score 2):

In pyinfra, every operation returns an object that has a `changed` property that does what you want:

```
dhcpconfig = file.put(…)
if dhcpconfig.changed:
    systemd.service(…)
```